# jQuery - checking existence of elements

Tags: jquery-selectors

Ok so basically I need to check,whether in my menu `#Container` exist any third level elements (`h3` to be exact) and if yes give them some attribute. If not give this attribute to second level element (`h2`) which always exists. Is :

```
if ($('h3')) {
  //some attribute
} else {
 //some attribute
};
```

the right method ?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use .length for this, it's 0/false if there aren't any matches:

```
if ($('h3').length) {
 //some attribute
} else {
 //some attribute
};
```

Short version, less readable:

```
$($('h3').length ? 'h3' : 'h2').addClass("bob");
```

Answer (score 3):

.....

```
if ($('#Container h3').length) {
  //some attribute
} else {
 //some attribute
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the length of the returned jQuery object

```
if ($('h3').length != 0)) {
    $('h3').attr(...);
}
else {
    $('h2').attr(...);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To make it more readable, I offer this tweak:

```
var h3ElementsExist = $('h3').length
if (h3ElementsExist) {
  //some attribute
} else {
 //some attribute
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I just realized an answer I posted to this feature a simple way to add a jQuery plugin for this was deleted a long time ago. Why? I don't know.

In conclusion, `ele.length` is simple, but not really elegant when you consider the fundamental flaws. It doesn't maintain jQuery style markup which could damage readability as well as forcing this in a "if" statement when this really "appears" like something jQuery should handle "naturally". Thus it does. If all your doing is seeking to apply an "attribute" to an exist element, you can simply make the call, with no if statement. If the element exist, it will get the new attribute. If it doesn't exist, it won't hurt anything or do anything other than continue on.

For example:

```
$('#Container h3').css('background', 'red');
```

This will make any existing `H3` tags within an element *id'd* as `Container` have a `red` background, if they exist. If they don't exist, this code will, essentially, be ignored. However, if you wanted to do more, and maintain jQuery "*chainability*" as well as maintain jQuery style markup, then I would suggest a plugin I wrote that adds **`$.exist()`** to jQuery.

It allows for a variety of ways to call with a parameter for callbacks as well. Simply put, you can use it in an if statement such as `if ($('h3').exist() {` or you can create a 1 to 2 callback methods. The callback methods are pure and simple. If only 1 is supplied, (or simply the *first* callback method) it is the "***exist***" callback method. In other words, if the element exist, it will fire, and then return the element(s) thus maintaining jQuery "*chainability*". However, if it doesn't exist, nothing will happen, *unless* there is a second callback method provided. Then it will fire your second callback method, much like the "*else*" of the aforementioned if statement.

Some examples here:

```
$('#Container h3').exist(function(boolTrue, elements, indexPerEach) { /* DO WORK */ });
```

of with 2 callbacks

```
$('#Container h3').exist(function(boolTrue, elements, indexPerEach) { /* DO WORK */ },
function(boolFalse, elements) { /* Elements did NOT EXIST - DO WORK */ });
```

See more example and get minified version of plugin [<kbd>HERE</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/cEUR5/6/)

```
/*---PULIGIN---*/
;;(function($){$.exist||($.extend({exist:function(){var a,c,d;if(arguments.length)for(x in arguments)switch(typeof arguments[x]){case "function":"undefined"==typeof c?c=arguments[x]:d=arguments[x];break;case "object":if(arguments[x]instanceof jQuery)a=arguments[x];else{var b=arguments[x];for(y in b)"function"==typeof b[y]&&("undefined"==typeof c?c=b[y]:d=b[y]),"object"==typeof b[y]&&b[y]instanceof jQuery&&(a=b[y]),"string"==typeof b[y]&&(a=$(b[y]))}break;case "string":a=$(arguments[x])}if("function"==typeof c){var e=0<a.length?!0:!1;if(e)return a.each(function(b){c.apply(this,[e,a,b])});if("function"==typeof d)return d.apply(a,[e,a]),a}return 1>=a.length?0<a.length?!0:!1:a.length}}),$.fn.extend({exist:function(){var a=[$(this)];if(arguments.length)for(x in arguments)a.push(arguments[x]);return $.exist.apply($,a)}}))})(jQuery);
/*---PULIGIN---*/
```

See more info posted about it on another answer [<kbd>HERE</kbd>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044/is-there-an-exists-function-for-jquery#answer-13313296)

Answer (score 0):

Check the size or length of the returned jQuery object

```
if ($('h3').size() != 0)) {
    $('h3').attr(...);
}
else {
    $('h2').attr(...);
}
```

or

```
if ($('h3').length != 0)) {
    $('h3').attr(...);
}
else {
    $('h2').attr(...);
}
```